# Button Background Margin

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am looking for a way to have a background image in a button with a dedicated margin. Right now I have something like this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="2,0">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None">
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <DrawingImage Drawing="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

This fills my button completely with the image. Which is (I think...) the correct behavior. Now I want to have a small margin around the background image. I didn't find a way to do this, because neither the image brush nor the drawing image offer such property. I know that I can use the button content to have an image which offers the margin, but with this approach the button image behaves strange when I put the button within a scroll viewer control (the button grows when I resize the view, but the image keeps small). What is the best way to handle this?

- UPDATE *

Based on the answers below the custom style seems to be the best fit. Anyway, perhaps my problem is not really the button itself but the scrollviewer which is around the button. I have attached two images first with scrollview and second without. With the scroll viewer the image is small and does not fit the button, so perhaps this is the root cause here? Any suggestions:

[image: With Scrollviewer]

Without Scrollviewer:

[image: Without Scrollviewer]

Comment: It seems that you need to set `Padding`.

Comment: I think I found the issue for the scrollviewer problem. It was the missing property "HorizontalContentAlignment" and "VerticalContentAlignment" to "Stretch". Sometimes WPF makes me really crazy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Padding, Margin is used to set the spacing outside of the control where as Padding is used to provide space inside the bounded control, and you should do the following things,

1. instead of **Background** property you have to set **Content**
   Property of Button.
2. instead of **ImageBrush** use **Image** control
   as a button content.

```
<Button
        Grid.Column="3"
        Width="300"
        Height="30"
        Margin="2,0"
        Padding="5"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="in.png" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `Margin` or a `Padding` **will not work** here. The `Margin` is applied around the button, not in the button and the `Padding` is applied to the inner `ContentPresenter`. in other words, the padding will be around the `Content`, but not around the `Background` because that is not part of the content.

Your choices to solve the issue are:

- Create a drawing that already contains the margin (which will not stay the same when rescaled).
- Create the image as content of the `Button`, then `Padding` will work (recommended).

  ```
  <Button Grid.Column="3" Padding="2, 0">
     <Button.Content>
        <Image Stretch="Fill">
           <Image.Source>
              <DrawingImage Drawing="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
           </Image.Source>
        </Image>
     </Button.Content>
  </Button>
  ```
- Edit the default control template and style to change the way the background is applied. This can be tedious and affects other visual states than just the static one, so be careful if you choose to do this. Here is an *example* of how it could look like.

  ```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
  <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
     <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate>
              <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Border x:Name="border" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                 <Border x:Name="innerBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                 </Border>
              </Border>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                 </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
  ```

  If you put these style in a resource dictionary in scope, you can use it like this.

  ```
  <Button Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Padding="20, 0">
     <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None">
           <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
              <DrawingImage Drawing="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
           </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
     </Button.Background>
  </Button>
  ```

  Of course, if you omit the style key, you could also make it implicit, if you want.